# Evaluate calls my function multiple times when the function generates an error

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, hold

If I execute a line of code with `Evaluate` I find some unexpected behavior when the code returns an error. Here is a minimal example. Let `f`

```
f[x_, y_] := (WriteString["stdout", "Hi "];
              y /. x);
```

Now if I call

```
In[1]:= Evaluate[f[a->1,a]]
```

> Hi
>
> Out[1]= 1

As expected, while if I do

```
In[2]:= Evaluate[f[a,b]]
```

this obviously results in an error (because `a` is not a `Rule`), but I can see that the function is evaluated multiple times

> Hi Hi Hi
>
> ReplaceAll: {a} is [etc...]
>
> Out[2]= b/. a

As you see it is evaluated three times. The same instruction without the `Evaluate` returns the same but with only one "Hi."

I suspect that in order to throw the error Mathematica is enclosing that statement inside a held function and the Evaluate is causing it to evaluate again. But I can't figure out what's happening in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the top-level `Evaluate` interacting with the `HoldForm` wrappers returned by `` MessageMenu`Dump`$GetStack `` (which is defined as `Stack[_]`). This function is called twice when building the error message, explaining the two additional calls.

#### How to find this

We start by changing the definitions of the question a bit to make tracking easier:

```
g[] := (WriteString["stdout", "Hi "]; marker)

f[x_, y_] := (g[];
   y /. x);
```

Now we `Trace` the problematic call, using `Unevaluated` to protect the `Evaluate` from being evaluated too early. We also need `TraceInternal->True`. The trace is filtered for calls to `g` and `TraceAbove->True` is used to show the stack leading up to the call:

```
Trace[Unevaluated@Evaluate[f[a, b]], g, TraceInternal -> True, 
 TraceAbove -> True]
(* long trace... *)
```

We can now search for `marker` using the search functionality (this indicates that `g` has actually been evaluated. We find three occurences:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Other tools: (1) `On[HoldForm]`, though the printing of the trace messages causes even more greetings; one can inspect the stack. (2) This makes the role of `HoldForm` a bit clearer: `f[x_, y_] := (Print[Stack[_HoldForm]];
   y /. x);` (3) This gets rid of the problem: `Unprotect@HoldForm;
SetAttributes[HoldForm, HoldAllComplete];
Protect@HoldForm;`, though I don't like changing system functions. (+1)